# Eviar correos desde gmail con swift mailer en yii2

Tags: yii2, gmail, email, smtp

estoy intentando configurar mi aplicación yii2 para que envíe correos desde mi cuenta de gmail, ya habilité "Permitir el acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras" en mi cuenta. Configuré el swift mailer como  muestro debajo, todo lo demás (Modelo y Controlador) lo dejo como viene por defecto en la plantilla básica de yii2. Cuando intento enviar el correo me sale el error Swift_TransportException "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. #0]". Alguién sabe como solucionarlo??? gracias de antemano...

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'user@gmail.com',
            'password' => '******',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Esto lo estas haciendo en local? o en un servidor de produccion?

Comment: todavía la aplicación está en desarrollo en un servidor local.

Comment: Revisa este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517281/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-conne tu problema puede deberse a causa del host, puerto u la IPV

Comment: Ya prové diferentes host´s y diferentes puertos sin éxito, cree usted que se deba a que mi pc no tiene full acceso a internet, sino a través de un proxy ???

Comment: Es una posibilidad, el proxy no sabemos que tanto permite la comunicación. Si pudiese revisar en una red sin limites... para descartar esta posibilidad.

Comment: prueba de cambiar  'encryption' => 'ssl', 'port' => '465',

Comment: Hola, disculpen la demora a los que me ayudan. Probé en una red sin límites sin éxito pero obtube errores diferentes. con tls y puerto 587 me dio el error "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed" y con ssl y puerto 465 el error "Connection could not be established with host 74.125.141.108 [ #0]" ... Saludos

Comment: Dejo el comentario por si le es útil, Gmail tiene desactivado por defecto el acceso de aplicaciones "menos seguras", esta es una de las principales causas del porque aun estando bien configurado no se puede enviar el correo. Revisa que tenga **desactivada** esta opción.

Answer (score -1):

El problema se da porque no encuentra la conexión a gmail, ingresa tu correo y clave de gmail en las siguientes lineas, así te va a funcionar en servidor local y si es de un host tendrá que ingresar los datos del propio servidor.

```
        'username' => 'user@gmail.com',
        'password' => '******',
```